# Logstash - how to prevent loading duplicate records

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

we have a simple index called employees in which we have only 2 fields firstname, lastname. using logstash script, we load our employees data. We dont want to store duplicate records into the index even though we have duplicates in the data file. In this case, if firstname + lastname are same, then the record should not be added to the index.

```
logstash script is:

input { 
   file {
        path => "C:/employees.csv"
    } 
   }
filter {
    csv {
        columns => [
          "firstname",
          "lastname"
        ]
        separator => ","
        }
    }
output {
 elasticsearch{
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
   index => "employees"
    }
}

data file - employees.csv

john,doe
jane,doe
john,doe - this record should not be added to the index.

I went through lot of documentation and searched a lot for adding conditions in the filter clause. however, no luck so far.

Can any one provide inputs on this.

thanks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the Elasticsearch mapping [`_id`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/mapping-id-field.html) field. If you set that field based on a hash of *lastname*/*firstname* (or something similar) per row, you should avoid inserting duplicate data.

Elasticsearch is [autogenerating unique ids](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-doc.html#_autogenerating_ids) per row if you don't specify what you'd like that `_id` to be.

**Edit:**
If *lastname* + *firstname* is unique enough for your dataset

```
... 
output { 
    elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
        index => "employees" 
        _id => "%{lastname}%{firstname}" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide me the syntax to create the index based on a hash of lastname+first name. Thank you

Comment: Accepted it as the answer. I have 2 more questions. 1) if i get the same record with other fields changed, the record is not updating. basically, i am looking for upsert. for eg: his designation, salary is changed, then the existing record needs to be updated. any inputs on this? 2) will there be any performance overhead on using hashed id(firstname+lastname) instead of auto generated id from elastic? Thanks much in advance

Comment: This no longer works in Logstash.

```
Unknown setting '_id' for elasticsearch
```